# Invoices started processing

Tags: passive-voice

Is it correct to say "could you check if the invoices started processing"? If not, what is the correct way to say this?

Comment: Some people sometimes say things like this, but because the invoices are actually *being acted on*, rather than *causing / controlling* their status, many people would avoid it. So *...check if [the] **invoice processing** has started* (feasibly *...if the invoices **have started to be processed***) might be a safer choice. This isn't really a matter of what's "correct" - it's what's ***idiomatically natural***.

Comment: ...Note that with similar contexts, such as *...if **invoice payments** have started / ...if the invoices have **started to be paid***, it's *much* less acceptable to say *...if the invoices have **started paying***, so if you only want to learn one construction, learn the passive ***started to be...*** Or learn how to create a more natural "verb subject" such as ***invoice processing, invoice payments.***

Comment: Could you check if the invoices are being processed?

Comment: Hello ZviBar and welcome to ELL. On this site, we only allow questions about specific aspects of English, like a grammar point, the meaning of a phrase, etc, so I have closed this question to new answers. Please [edit] your question to tell us which parts of this sentence you already know are correct, and which part(s) you're not sure about. Then tag me by putting @gotube in a comment, and I'll reopen the question to new answers. :)

Answer (score 7):

Although it’s not an extremely common usage, it is acceptable and would certainly be understood. It’s parallel to *Dinner will be another twenty minutes now; the pizza has only just **started baking***.

More idiomatic paraphrases are *Could you check whether they’ve started processing the invoices*, and even *…the invoices have started being processed*. (Note, though, that this latter has a touch of the odd about it because things like invoices are typically seen as fairly inert and passive, so even so abstract an action as starting to be processed seems a bit too active—and even intentional—to ascribe to them. Still, there’s nothing off about *We’d better warn accounting, the invoices have **started arriving***.)

Comment: I think the "dinner" example with [TO BE] is a bit of a special case. OP's example steers more towards something like *Dinner **serves / dishes up** in 20 minutes* - which is sorta okay in some contexts, but definitely not so natural as *Dinner **is** in 20 minutes*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, my point with the dinner example is, as highlighted in bold, the *pizza … started baking* to parallel the OP’s *invoices started processing*.

Comment: Without doubt he "pizza" example is the same as the OP's (or "dinner serves..."). I'm just making the point that we're far more accommodating of "unusual" subject+verb combinations when the specific verb is [TO BE].

Comment: Ooops! Just noticed what you meant!

Comment: I find this type of usage is very common in (e.g.) UK workplaces, where people will say that 'the payroll has started processing', 'the cakes are baking', 'the turkey is roasting'. Also a car owner may say 'it drives nicely'.

Comment: Indeed, @MichaelHarvey, all of those are heard in the US too, along with “The car *handles* nicely.”